# Differences between Чей/Чья and Кого

Tags: узус, сленг

If you want to make a question related to *possession*, when is it preferable to use *Чей/Чья ...?* and when is it better to use *Кого...?* ? Are both options grammatically correct?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Чей/чья** is the only one you can use here. **Кого** in a possession-related question would be as much of a solecism as "of whom" instead of "whose".

Comment: You may still see this form in the old books, such as those written by Gogol.